# Downgrading of a line in version d3.js v4 to d3.js v3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i want to know what the equivalent of this is in the v3 version of d3.js
currently I have this working on version 4 of d3.js

```
  var line = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveBasis)
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.apotential); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.current); });
```

Comment: `var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.apotential); })
    .y(function(d) { return  y(d.current);  })
    .interpolate('basis');`

Comment: yes! I need calificate you. can you help me with this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46369492/add-a-point-to-a-line-in-d3-js